Problem regarding ratio of two definite integrals
Let
$$A =\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-x}   dx$$
$$B =\int_0^1 \frac{(\ln x) ^2}{(1-x)^2} dx$$
Prove that $|B|=2|A|$
My attempt:
$$B =\int_0^1 \frac{(\ln x) ^2}{(1-x)^2}
= 
\frac{(lnx)^2}{(1-x)}-(\int_0^1\frac{ln((x)(1-x))}{(x)(1-x)})dx$$
And I'm stuck here...
(It's a high school level problem)

Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? Could you edit your post to include some of you thoughts?

Hi! Tried using integration by parts with (lnx)2 and (1/1-x)^2 but made no further progress

$B=\infty$ while $A$ is finite...

Edit your post to include what you have tried and where you are stuck

@vanderWolf not with the current wording (but perhaps the question was edited)

@vanderWolf WA says that $B= \pi^2 /3$.

@Someon could you include your attempt in full as part of the question? People trying to answer your question will have no idea what level you're studying at, what you are familiar with, and so on, so while you might get an answer, it may not be as useful to you for doing other questions as you might like.

Putting $x=e^{-t}$ we get integral like the integral from the definition of Bernoulli numbers.

No need to compute $A$. For $B$, just use integration by parts; set $u=\log(x)$. You'll need to figure out a couple of limits but then you can write $B$ in terms of $A$. (The question doesn't ask you to compute the integrals, it asks for their ratio. You need to use that!)

We have
$$A =\int_0^1 \frac{\log x}{1-x} \;dx$$
and
$$B =\int_0^1 \frac{(\log x) ^2}{(1-x)^2} \;dx$$
($\log$ refers to the natural logarithm.) We want the ratio of $A$ and $B$.
Leave $A$ as it is. To evaluate $B$, we use integration by parts: let $u=\log(x)$ and $\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{\log(x)}{(1-x)^2}$. This gives $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$ and (using integration by parts again)
$$v=\log(1-x)+\frac{x\log(x)}{1-x}$$
Now,
$$B=\left[\color{blue}{\log(x)\cdot\log(1-x)+\frac{x(\log(x))^2}{1-x}}-\int \frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\; dx - \int \frac{\log(x)}{1-x}\; dx\right]_0^1$$
You can prove that the limits as $x\to 0$ and $x\to 1$ of the part in blue are both $0$.
So
$$B=-\int_0^1 \frac{\log x}{1-x} \;dx-\int_0^1 \frac{\log (1-x)}{x} \;dx$$
You'll see that the first integral is just $A$, and the second is also $A$ after a substitution; so $B=-2A$.

A couple of points to note:

To finish the answer, you need to show that that's the correct form for $v$, and that the limits in blue work out.
You might wonder how I knew to try $u=\log(x)$. I didn't; I tried a bunch of other possibilities first.
Note that you don't need to evaluate $A$ and $B$. This is really important! Sometimes evaluating them is the easiest way, but not always.


Brilliant! Makes sense now... Thanks

No worries! There might be a still better way (it's a bit tough for high school!), but I don't think you're likely to need to actually work out the two integrals. It depends a bit on what you've been studying; if it's something like Taylor series, you could try that approach too.

We can also obtain/check the result as follows by
$$2A+B=\int_0^1 \frac{2\ln x}{1-x}  +\frac{\ln^2 x}{(1-x)^2} dx=\left[\frac{x\ln^2 x}{1-x}\right]_0^1=0$$
since
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x\ln^2 x}{1-x}=0,\;\;\lim_{x\to 1^-} \frac{x\ln^2 x}{1-x}=0$$

Very nice!! I suspect that's what they were looking for

@ChrisLewis I'm not sure, ineed also your way is very fine!
